# Pulling min and max values from a random array to display

Tags: c#, arrays, random, max, min

So, like the title says I need to pull the min and max values from an array I've created that utilizes a random number generator to fill it. I get the feeling it's probably the Math class of operators that I need to use (IE, the math.floor and math.ceiling) but if that's so I'm not quite sure how to utilize them with the array. I suppose the bottom line is that I don't quite understand how arrays work, even though I've already done a couple of assignments utilizing them. Here's what I have so far (I have to display all values in the listbox and give average and min/max for this assignment)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    int SIZE = 10;
    int[] nummers = new int[SIZE];
    Random rand = new Random();
    int total = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < nummers.Length; index++)
    {
        nummers[index] = rand.Next(1, 100);

    }
    foreach (int value in nummers)
    {
        total += value;
        listBox1.Items.Add(value);
    }
    total/= 10;
    label3.Text = total.ToString("d");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Linq to make your life easier:

```
int minimum = numbers.Min();
int maximum = numbers.Max();
```

---

Old style:

modify the foreach to be like this:

```
int maximum = int.MinValue;
int minimum = int.MaxValue;
foreach (int value in nummers)
    {
        if (value < minimum) { minimum = value; }
        if (value > maximum) { maximum = value; }

        total += value;
        listBox1.Items.Add(value);
    }
```

Comment: and `numbers.Average();` and `numbers.Sum();` so your last foreach isn't needed anymore.

Comment: you mean, to actually do the algorithm? ok i'll update the answer with the old style ;) the real deal :P

Comment: From a readability point of view I like the (original) solution however it does iterate the array once more than is actually needed (this of course is of little concern with 10 elements)

Comment: That's why i included the "old style" answer in the already existing foreach so that everything is done in one pass.

Comment: Thanks guys and yeah it's a makeup assignment for something I missed earlier in the semester so he gave me a harder array assignment to fiddle with.

Comment: Yay! It works. Thank you! And just to make sure I understand basically what you've done is nested two if statements for me, telling the program to compare the array built in variable "value" to the min/max variables declared at the beginning and to assign it once it's true? Oh, and the foreach loop I already had is what makes it cycle through all the array numbers?

Comment: What i did, is inside the foreach that iterates through the whole array i also compare each value in the array which is stored in the "value" variable inside the loop with the max/min values i declared above and in case they are larger/smaller than the existing min/max values i set them as being the current min/max. And at the end of the loop you will end up with the overall minimum and maximum of the whole array. Doing it all in the same loop is an optimization, doesn't make sense to do them in separate loops, only maybe for even more readability of the code.

Comment: Thanks a ton for both the code and the clearer understanding of what it's doing.